# Music file rhythm and intensity detection on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, audio, xamarin.forms, spectrum

Our product is a dimmable light bulb, connected via Bluetooth and App, App can adjust the brightness (color) of the bulb, the brightness value is 1-100.

Now the App wants to add a function that automatically dims according to music (Mp3). While playing music, it automatically adjusts the brightness of the light according to the rhythm and sound size of the music.

The music has been played using https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/tree/master/SimpleAudioPlayer

My question is, when playing music (Mp3), how do I convert the rhythm and intensity of the music to a 1-100 number and send it as a brightness value to the light bulb?

A lot of C# (Windows-based) music analysis examples were found online, but Xamarin was not found.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: it's doubtful you're going to find any existing package that does something this specialized.  You're just going to have do some research and write it yourself.

Comment: I am the developer, I used C# and now I use Xamarin to develop the app. @Davesoft

Answer (score 0):

Sounds cool! There are two parts to your problem,

- Enhancing the audio player - Since you have implemented the Audio Player already, all you need to do is add a Value changed event to the slider, as shown in [this official Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/slider), so that changing the value of the slider will now also communicate with your device/bulb
- Communicating with your device - This will depend on how your device accepts values over bluetooth. We wouldn't be able to know for sure what serial values your bulb is accepting, but you have to send serial data values through bluetooth. You can use [this](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) to help simplify with this part.

Comment: I have implemented the Bluetooth BLE control of the light bulb, and you can also use the slider to manually control the brightness of the light. At present, when it is desired to realize the music playing, the brightness of the lamp is automatically controlled according to the intensity of the music. The difficulty is to convert the music to a digital stream of 1-100 indicating the intensity.

Comment: Could you upload the audio to a server at the beginning of the song, and that returns a json that has the intensity values for every 1/10th of a second. Especially since you were able to do this over a desktop already

Comment: This is an optional solution. @Saamer

Comment: @PaulZhang ok cool, since you are using .Net standard, have you looked into possibly using the nuget packages available for audio processing AudioTools, CSCore, SoundFingerprinting, etc?

Comment: @Sammer CSCore and SoundFingerprinting feel good, I will study it. Thank you for your suggestion!